# How to change UITypeEditor according a parent object's property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm testing the [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y900) and I want to choose a UIType editor according a parent object's property :

```
    public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        // Uses the IWindowsFormsEditorService to display a 
        // drop-down UI in the Properties window.
        IWindowsFormsEditorService edSvc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        if (edSvc != null)
        {
            AngleEditorTestControl t = context.Instance as AngleEditorTestControl;

            if (t != null)
            {
                // If the property TestValue is null or empty, the AngleControl is selected
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.TestValue))
                {
                    // Display an angle selection control and retrieve the value.
                    AngleControl angleControl = new AngleControl(
                        (bool)context.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(
                        context.Instance), edSvc);

                    edSvc.DropDownControl(angleControl);
                    return angleControl.Valeur;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otherwise I want the default UIType Editor (for Int32, float and double) will be selected
                    // ...
                }
            }

        }
        return value;

    }
```

How to do that ???

Thank you !

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I might hazard a guess, but I'm not sure what you meant by the default UITypeEditor.  Do you just mean the regular old textbox that is displayed when no Editor attribute is specified?